# How to bulk change more than 500 issues on SonarQube 6.x?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube6.3

Some bulks needed have over 100K issues.

Is there a way to bulk change more than the 500 issues in SonarQube 6.x?

The UI certainly does not allow to customize this. Where can I find the parameter/code/table in the database needed to change the 500 value ?

Comment: the question is always the why you want to do this, maybe you just do not need to change 100k issues :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do a bulk change of more than 500 issues, but you can update more than 500 using web services :

1. Get list of issues using [api/issues/search?p=1&ps=500](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/search)
2. Do the bulk change using [api/issues/bulk_change?issues=ISSUE1,ISSUE2,...](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/bulk_change) on found issues.

Repeat these 2 steps updating the `p` parameter of api/issues/search each time.